# MQTT-SN over UDP

Tags: udp, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to connect arduino to my laptop (Ubuntu) as a MQTT-SN client. Arduino is connected to Ubuntu over serial port. I need help in connecting MQTT-SN to mosquitto broker. Is there any opensource tool that can act as a bridge between Serial and mosquitto broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the title of this question says "Windows," I think you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558038/mqtt-sn-with-windows/28730254#28730254