# RSMB doesn't receive UDP messages

Tags: mqtt

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558038/mqtt-sn-with-windows/28730254#28730254) I tried to test RSMB broker with [mqtt-sn-tools](https://github.com/njh/mqtt-sn-tools) but I can't get it to work. When I try to publish a message I always get a `recv failed: Connection refused`.

I can see that the broker is listening for TCP connections on port 1883 but nothing about UDP. I can send messages using the mosquitto client because it uses a TCP connection.

Isn't RSMB supposed to handle UDP request?

Comment: Please insert teh relevant text from the links into your post.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your rsmb config file so we can see how you've set it up

Comment: It is resolved now, I updated the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, I need to run `./broker_mqtts` AND add `listener 1885 INADDR_ANY mqtts` line to the config file. I tested both serveral times, but never at the same time.